# Using object's innerText

Tags: vbscript

The `innerText` looks like this:

```
9999
NA 1299
1/1/2015

7:01:35 EST

Cleanup Time

12/31/2015

12/31/2015
```

I'm trying to work with an object's `innerText` by doing the following:

```
Set arr_data = Sys.Browser.("iexplore").Page("...")...

For i = 0 To array_data.length-1
    Set element = array_data(i)
    Set text = element.innerText //error happens on this line
    If InStr(text, "Cleanup Time")<> 0 Then 
        Log.Message("Found")
    Else
        Log.Message("Not Found")
    End If
Next
```

The error I am getting is:

> Microsoft VBSCript runtime error
>   Object required:'[string: "9999 IMP 9999"]'

I've also tried indexing by using

```
Set text = element.innerText(i)
```

But get a

> Unknown runtime error

I've checked the objects in the debugger up to the point of `Set` text, and everything looks good.

Comment: Can you post the HTML to go along with this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is we are trying to Set text, when we should just be using

```
text = element.outerText
```

Comment: Correct. The `Set` keyword must be used when assigning objects to variables. It must not be used when assigning primitive types (like strings).